# Why does my Ubuntu 20.04 logs show this whenever I boot?

Tags: 20.04, logs

Whenever I switch on my Ubuntu PC, the logs show
power: shutdown scheduled for (T - 20.0) seconds

[image: image of logs]

Comment: Is there any scheduled `shutdown` set by you?

Comment: no i didn't sheduled any shutdown, whenever i boot my ubuntu this appears in my logs